# Unable to load dll 'OraOps12.dll' . The specified module could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, oracle

I have an asp .net application which has reference to `Oracle.DataAccess.dll` .

I have Oracle Instant Client 19 running on my machine , when I build and deploy to IIS and try to run this app, I get an error:

> Unable to load dll 'OraOps12.dll . The specified module could not be
> found.

My friend has this app up and running , he has installed Oracle Instant Client 12c. I have two questions related to this.

a) *If its related to different flavours of Oracle db , where can I change in the application to use the 'Oracle 19' version instead of 'Oracle 12'?*

b) *I tried to find `OraOps12.dll` in my friend's machine but it was not found at all. How is it that asp .net application is able to refer to some dll which is not found in his machine at all.*

**Edit** :
I happened to right click on Oracle.DataAccess.dll and found the version as "4.121.2.0" . I am going through
https://www.nuget.org/packages/ODP.Oracle.DataAccess.x86/#release-body-tab
which says Oracle client needs to be installed.

According to this article can we install any Oracle Client or Oracle Client 12.1 version in particular?

Comment: The file can be either in the System32 folder or the SysWow64 folder.  Check project settings to see type of project (x86, 32,64).

Comment: It is not found in either 'System32' or 'SysWow64' folder and Settings of the project gives the following message "The project does not contain a default settings file. Click here to craete one'

Comment: Oracle Client and Oracle.DataAccess.dll must be the same architecture (i.e. 32-bit or 64-bit) and the version of them must match **exactly**.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: If I right click on Oracle.DataAccess and go to Properties , I get the Version as "4.121.2.0" and Runtime version "v4.0.30319" . How to find which Oracle Client version it is using?

Comment: Do the same on file `oci.dll`. But when you say "I have Oracle Instant Client 19 running on my machine" then the version is obviously different.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit: I downloaded Oracle 12.2 version and installed . So, the oci.dll has Product version "12.2.0.0" . Which Client version is Oracle.DataAccess referring to ?

Comment: Would be version 4.122.1.0

Comment: v4.0.30319 is Net 4.0 which is very old.  You probably do not have net 4.0 installed.  You want to download from here : https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/net-downloads.html  The connection string will depend on the oracle driver you download.  See : https://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle/

Comment: Of course net 4.0 is installed, should be part of any modern Windows. These version are not removed when newer .net are released and installed. See `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework` and `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64`. The connection string is the same for all versions.

Comment: .net 4.0 is already installed . Is the Oracle.DataAccess dll expecting Oracle client 12.1 version only to be installed in my machine?